# Make serverside strings safe for use in clientside scripts

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

I need to show the server exception in the client browser, but it seems there are some illegal characters inside the `exp.Message` which makes the client script to raise "unterminated string literal" error.
any idea to make strings such as `exp.Message` safe for client scripts?

```
catch (Exception exp) {
    string __script = string.Format(@"alert('{0}');", exp.Message);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "theError", __script, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a lot of search, finally found a solution in rick strahl's blog: [EncodeJsString](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)

```
using System.Web;

...

var encodedMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(exp.Message);
string __script = string.Format(@"alert('{0}');", encodedMessage);
```

Comment: unfortunately HtmlEncode did not help in this issue. i checked the return value of HtmlEncode. it seems that some illegal characters (such as single quotation marks) still there.